# Can I call cocos2d-x class method(c++) from objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x stuff.

I know that we can call Objective-c method from cocos2d-x. (using bridge class, ex) ObjCCall.mm.

But, on the contrary to that, 
is it possible to call cocos2d-x class's method(scene class method) from objective-c?

for example, 
when payment request completed in objective-c, I want to call display cocos2d-x scene's popup method.

any idea plz...

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

of course, you will need to compile it as objc++ and include the proper files.

```
- (void)method {
  SomeCppClass::Foo(1);
}
```

Comment: ok, but if the method is a instance class's method, how can I do it?

Comment: CCScene *scene = (CCScene*)MenuScene::create();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(CCTransitionSlideInT::create(0.8, scene));

Comment: I think you can create an instance using a static method, then you can call from the instance. for example, CCSprite* spr = CCSprite::create("file.png");        spr->setPosition(ccp(0,0));